# Check if printer supports postscript

Tags: c#, postscript, printers

is there any way to check if printer supports postscript, using C#? I need to check this before I do anything with my document.

Thanks,
Bartosz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use WMI potentially, however im not sure if this solution will be reliable

```
System.Management.ObjectQuery oq = new System.Management.ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");
ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oq);
ManagementObjectCollection moc = mos.Get();
foreach( ManagementObject mo in moc )
{

    string name = mo["Name"].ToString();
    string language = mo["DefaultLanguage"].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Printer: {0} -- Language: {1}", name, language));
}
```

[Lifted from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534207/is-there-a-way-to-determine-in-net-or-wmi-if-a-print-driver-will-print-to-pcl)

**Update**

Check here to see other fields that might be relevant

[Win32_Printer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363(v=vs.85).aspx)

In particular   `uint16   LanguagesSupported[];`

Comment: Thanks for help, I've already found this solution, but it not working for me - I'm getting NullReferenceException on mo["DefaultLanguage"].ToString();

Comment: Note that the installed printer driver may impact whether or not postscript is supported.

Answer (score 1):

Code, which I've finally used, with little changes:

```
System.Management.ObjectQuery oq = new System.Management.ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");
        ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oq);
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = mos.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {

            string name = mo["Name"].ToString();
            var language = mo["LanguagesSupported"];
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Printer: {0} -- Language: {1}", name, language==null ? 0 : (language as ushort[])[0]));
        }
```